# Sorting using ORDER BY on a JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I am trying to use `ORDER BY` to sort a query, but it is claiming there is a syntax error. My query looks like this before trying to sort:

```
SELECT u.*, s.*
FROM bands u
inner join statuses s on u.status_id = s.id
WHERE u.status_id = 1
LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit}
```

I have tried adding `ORDER BY` like this but is doesn't seem to be correct:

```
SELECT u.*, s.*
FROM bands u
inner join statuses s on u.status_id = s.id
WHERE u.status_id = 1
LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit} ORDER BY u.status_id
```

How can I use `ORDER BY` properly inside this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY` clause comes before `LIMIT`

```
SELECT u.*, s.*
FROM bands u
inner join statuses s on u.status_id = s.id
WHERE u.status_id = 1
ORDER BY u.status_id
LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit}
```

Comment: Sometimes the simple things are the hardest to figure out :) Thanks for the fast help.

Comment: hehe you are wlcome @Riboflavin

Answer (score 1):

You're amost there - you just have the ORDER and the LIMIT the wrong way round:

```
SELECT 
    u.*, s.* 
FROM 
    bands u inner join statuses s on u.status_id = s.id 
WHERE 
    u.status_id = 1 
ORDER BY u.status_id
LIMIT {$startpoint}, {$limit}
```